# Show product variation in woocommerce Added to cart message

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

In my WooCommerce store, when a variable product is added to cart I have the user stay on the product page.

The success notice message shows the product title along with the generic appendage, but I want it to show the variations with the product title in notices like so:

"Mens Coat - size: small“ has been added to your cart.

Rather than:

"Mens Coat“ has been added to your cart.

Currently running WooCommerce 3.3.1 and WP 4.9.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is dynamic so will work for any number of attributes added to a variable product.  It will handle simple product as per usual.

```
function modify_wc_add_to_cart_message( $message, $products ) {
    $attribute_label = '';
    $titles = array();
    $count  = 0;

    foreach ( $products as $product_id => $qty ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

        if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            foreach( $product->get_variation_attributes() as $attribute_name => $attribute_values ) {
                if( isset( $_REQUEST['attribute_' . strtolower( $attribute_name )] ) ) {
                    if( in_array( $_REQUEST['attribute_' . strtolower( $attribute_name )], $attribute_values ) ) {
                        if( ! empty( $attribute_label ) )
                            $attribute_label .= ', ';

                        $attribute_label .= $attribute_name . ' : ' . $_REQUEST['attribute_size'];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $titles[] = ( $qty > 1 ? absint( $qty ) . ' &times; ' : '' ) . sprintf( _x( '&ldquo;%s&rdquo;', 'Item name in quotes', 'woocommerce' ), strip_tags( get_the_title( $product_id ) ) . ( ! empty( $attribute_label ) ? ' - ' . $attribute_label : '' ) ) ;
        $count += $qty;
    }

    $titles     = array_filter( $titles );
    $added_text = sprintf( _n( '%s has been added to your cart.', '%s have been added to your cart.', $count, 'woocommerce' ), wc_format_list_of_items( $titles ) );

    if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) ) {
        $return_to = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect', wc_get_raw_referer() ? wp_validate_redirect( wc_get_raw_referer(), false ) : wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) );
        $message   = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( $return_to ), esc_html__( 'Continue shopping', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );
    } else {
        $message   = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' ) ), esc_html__( 'View cart', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );
    }

    return $message;
}

add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 'modify_wc_add_to_cart_message', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in the above code, where it references "attribute_size" - it works for the OP because that IS actually the name of the variable, but if you're using it for anything else, that whole line needs to be:

```
$attribute_label .= $attribute_name . ' : ' . $_REQUEST['attribute_' . strtolower( $attribute_name )];
```