# Show product variation attributes on added to cart message in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, notice

In WooCommerce, when someone adds a product to the basket a notice message is shown to confirm. Rather than showing the parent, I want to be able to show the variation that a customer has put into their shopping basket.

I'm using Andrew Schultz's code from the answer to [Show product variation in woocommerce Added to cart message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916989/show-product-variation-in-woocommerce-added-to-cart-message/48932811#48932811) I guess that the hooks or names have changed because what's happening is that "pa_subject" is being shown when it should say "Geography", for example.

Any ideas how to change it?

```
function modify_wc_add_to_cart_message( $message, $products ) {
    $attribute_label = '';
    $titles = array();
    $count  = 0;

    foreach ( $products as $product_id => $qty ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

        if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            foreach( $product->get_variation_attributes() as $attribute_name => $attribute_values ) {
                if( isset( $_REQUEST['attribute_' . strtolower( $attribute_name )] ) ) {
                    if( in_array( $_REQUEST['attribute_' . strtolower( $attribute_name )], $attribute_values ) ) {
                        if( ! empty( $attribute_label ) )
                            $attribute_label .= ', ';

                        $attribute_label .= $attribute_name . ' : ' . $_REQUEST['attribute_size'];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $titles[] = ( $qty > 1 ? absint( $qty ) . ' &times; ' : '' ) . sprintf( _x( '&ldquo;%s&rdquo;', 'Item name in quotes', 'woocommerce' ), strip_tags( get_the_title( $product_id ) ) . ( ! empty( $attribute_label ) ? ' - ' . $attribute_label : '' ) ) ;
        $count += $qty;
    }

    $titles     = array_filter( $titles );
    $added_text = sprintf( _n( '%s has been added to your cart.', '%s have been added to your cart.', $count, 'woocommerce' ), wc_format_list_of_items( $titles ) );

    if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) ) {
        $return_to = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect', wc_get_raw_referer() ? wp_validate_redirect( wc_get_raw_referer(), false ) : wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) );
        $message   = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( $return_to ), esc_html__( 'Continue shopping', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );
    } else {
        $message   = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' ) ), esc_html__( 'View cart', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );
    }

    return $message;
}
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 'modify_wc_add_to_cart_message', 10, 2 );
```

[image: scamp of return]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the code throw some errors when debug is enabled:

> **Notice:** Undefined index: attribute_size in ../wp-content/themes/storefront-child/functions.php on line xxxx

Essentially with this line:

```
$attribute_label .= $attribute_name . ' : ' . $_REQUEST['attribute_size'];
```

It seem that this code was made to handle a "size" custom attribute, instead of any.

It also displays the woocommerce attribute slug starting with "**`pa_`**" instead of the attribute taxonomy label name:

[image]

So to make it work and display the correct attributes label names with their term name values, use the following revisited code version:

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 'change_add_to_cart_message', 10, 2 );
function change_add_to_cart_message( $message, $products ) {
    $titles = array();
    $count  = 0;

    foreach ( $products as $product_id => $qty ) {
        // Get the WC_Product object instance
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        if( $product->get_type() === 'variable' ) {
            $variation_attributes = array();
            foreach( $product->get_variation_attributes() as $taxonomy => $terms_slugs ) {
                $wc_attribute_name = wc_variation_attribute_name( $taxonomy );
                if( isset( $_REQUEST[$wc_attribute_name] ) ) {
                    if( in_array( $_REQUEST[$wc_attribute_name], $terms_slugs ) ) {
                        $term_name = get_term_by( 'slug', $_REQUEST[$wc_attribute_name], $taxonomy )->name;
                        $variation_attributes[] = wc_attribute_label( $taxonomy ) . ': ' . $term_name;
                    }
                }
            }
            $variation_attributes = implode(', ', $variation_attributes);
        }

        $titles[] = ( $qty > 1 ? absint( $qty ) . ' &times; ' : '' ) . sprintf( _x( '&ldquo;%s&rdquo;', 'Item name in quotes', 'woocommerce' ), strip_tags( get_the_title( $product_id ) ) . ( ! empty( $variation_attributes ) ? ' - ' . $variation_attributes : '' ) ) ;
        $count += $qty;
    }

    $titles     = array_filter( $titles );
    $added_text = sprintf( _n( '%s has been added to your cart.', '%s have been added to your cart.', $count, 'woocommerce' ), wc_format_list_of_items( $titles ) );

    if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) ) {
        $return_to = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect', wc_get_raw_referer() ? wp_validate_redirect( wc_get_raw_referer(), false ) : wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) );
        $message   = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( $return_to ), esc_html__( 'Continue shopping', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );
    } else {
        $message   = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' ) ), esc_html__( 'View cart', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );
    }

    return $message;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

---

**To display only the term names without the taxonomy label name**

Replace in the code this line:

```
$variation_attributes[] = wc_attribute_label( $taxonomy ) . ': ' . $term_name;
```

by this one:

```
$variation_attributes[] = $term_name;
```

You will get something like:

[image]

Comment: You are an absolute star! This has worked beautifully. Thank you @loictheaztec